# Can I Embed Twitter search timeline and pass the search parameter dynamically?

Tags: javascript, python, search, twitter, timeline

Is it possible to create a dynamic timeline? I want to embed a search timeline where I can change the search key with some javascript or python. If this isn't possible, could anyone suggest a workaround? I suppose I could use the GET search and embed each tweet...

Comment: Not 100% sure what you're asking here (e.g. are you asking if you can search different terms, or amalgamate the results of different searches?). Do you have an example we can look at?

Comment: Really don't get why this was closed. Everyone trying to do what heri0n tries to do ends up at this page. With twitter you can create an embedded timeline widget on their site, but the search parameters are hard-coded.